# Java - Ignore case checking user input

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if the user input matches anything in a Set or List, but I am currently using .contains().  Obviously this is not working when the user inputs something that is not the correct case, so I was thinking of using .matches( regex ), but am not a professional regexer.

Would could I use Regex or Pattern to check if the user input matches anything in a List, case aside.

Thank you.

I did just notice that I will have to use a for-loop to get the elements out of my Set before comparing them with .matches().

Comment: You could take the original input and transform it to lowercase, then compare it to whatever you want.

Comment: You can just check for `input.toLowerCase().contains(...)`

Comment: Thanks Flipybitz and Jack.  Seems like sometimes you're learning too much too fast, and you forget about the simple things... Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily convert both strings into lowercase or both into uppercase and then do the matching.

```
for(int i=0;i<myList.length-1;i++){
       if(myString.toLowerCase().contains(myList.get(i).toLowerCase())){
           // your code if myString is contained within a String in the List
       }
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<myList.length-1;i++){
       if(myString.toUpperCase().contains(myList.get(i).toUpperCase())){
           // your code if myString is contained within a String in the List
       }
}
```

Comment: Why bother upper/lower casing when you can just use String.equalsIgnoreCase()?

Comment: String.equalsIgnoreCase() checks whether that it is that actual string not more not less. we need contains to check whether that it contains the string not equals to the exact string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE with the Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you can't use `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`. `Regex` is not needed for this.  If you use a `List`, you can use `.stream().anyMatch()` with this `Predicate`:

```
c -> c.equalsIgnoreCase(data)
```

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> check = new ArrayList() {{
        add("dog");  
        add("CAT");
        add("oWl");
        add("GiraFFe");
    }};

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter data: ");
    String data = scanner.nextLine();

    if (check.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.equalsIgnoreCase(data))) {
        System.out.println("Data found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Data not found");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Enter data: gIRAffE
Data found

Enter data: lamb
Data not found
```

Comment: String.equalsIgnoreCase() checks whether that it is the full string. OP needs contains() to check if it *contains* the string, not *equals* to it.

Answer (score 0):

If a `Set` implementation is okay (meaning you don't need to store duplicate words), you could use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) with a case-insensitive [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Set<String> setOfWords = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

This way, you can feed the user input directly into `contains`. The following test code

```
setOfWords.addAll(Arrays.asList("ab", "cd", "ef"));
System.out.println(setOfWords.contains("AB"));
System.out.println(setOfWords.contains("cD"));
System.out.println(setOfWords.contains("Ef"));
```

prints out

```
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you have three options (some have already been stated).

- STRING.toLowerCase.contains();
- STRING.equalsIgnoreCase();
- A regex with [a-zA-Z]

Answer (score -1):

There's a string method called `equalsIgnoreCase` that may do what you want.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are working with strings, you can loop through the List or Set and check using `str.equalsIgnoreCase(strToCompare)`.

Answer (score -1):

Lets call your string input. Do the following to check if its the same, ignoring capitalization.

```
boolean isItEqual = input.equalsIgnoreCase("I am the string you want! :D");
```